# How can read/write serial port of client machine from ASP.Net Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on Smart Card Reader application. A Card Reader Device attached to serial port via usb and then by the help of an API (DLL) I can communicate with Device. This all work fine in Windows Form Application.
But now we need to create an asp.net web application so that our customer can use this device from any location via web. I have created a web application and used this DLL working fine in web application on localhost. But how can do this, that this will work on any of client browser and communicate client's serial port via DLL.

Comment: This is ***completely*** not how client/server web apps work.

Comment: The only way would be to install some kind of application on the client machine as well - the server code is running on the server, not the client, that's kind of the whole point. There really isn't a way to do this nicely. There's options like using an ActiveX control, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having a web application in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Luaan for your valuable and helpful comments. I am going to read about ActiveX to decide either should be used or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't import your dll in the client. You'll have to use ActiveX, Java, Silverlight or even Flash to access the card reader from the browser. And even so, the browser will ask the user authorization to break the browser safety "sandboxing" preventing access to local resource from the server.

Comment: Can you share/suggest some helpful workflow/article on how this can be achieved using Java, because now Silverlight is not supported in google chrome and Firefox, ActiveX also works with IE. Is the same thing possible with javascript too ?